# Estimate average percentage error based on another gaussian measurement

Tags: estimation, heteroscedasticity, measurement-error

I have a model where the error is proportional to the throughput. This is, the observations I got come from a measurement instrument that has some error and it measures material going through in little buckets. I am approximating the model as follows

$$
x_i = x~(1 + \epsilon_X) \\ \epsilon_X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X)
$$

I am also able to determine via another instrument, the total material before and after, so I am able to state (after simplifying)

$$
\delta_i = \delta + \epsilon_D' \approx x_i \\ \epsilon_D' = \epsilon_D^1 - \epsilon_D^2 \\ \epsilon_D^{\{1,2\}} \sim N(\mu_D, \sigma_D)
$$

The mean $\mu_D$ does not matter, as it cancels out in $\epsilon_D'$, but **the mean $\epsilon_X$, if not zero, is what I am after**. Things get complicated because the variance of $x_i$ depends on the actual throughput, so it seems I have heteroscedasticity in the model.

Put other way, $\epsilon_X$ is given as a random percentage of the measured quantity.

So, I have a number of $\delta_i$ readings, with random noise; and another set of $x_i$ readings with noise as above; they should match, but they don't due to noise. Actually, I am interested in the problem of finding out if the noise in $x_i$ is not zero-mean.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Update**

For what is worth, in addition to *Alecos'* answer, I tried also what *seanv507* suggested: by averaging $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n(Ln(x_i)-Ln(\delta_i))$, and then reverting with $Exp(.)$. It is very close to the ratio model (as said $1+x \approx e^x$ for small *x*) with the additional *advantage* that $x_i$ is is never negative under this model (if this is what one wants).

Comment: Your present specification has a nonzero chance that the error term will flip the sign of $x$; is this actually possible?

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. Although it is possible, one can safely assume that $\sigma_X << 1$ and $\mu_X$ is near zero; so, that event is very unlikely. I am interested in a model to find $\mu_X$ and its statistical properties.

Comment: "*one can safely assume that $σ_X<<1$ and $μ_X$ is near zero*" -- did you mean to insert a 'not' between 'is' and 'near'?

Comment: Nope, when $\mu_X$ is near zero and $\sigma_X << 1$, then $x_i$ = $x~(1+\epsilon_X)$ will stay near the true $x$. And, yes, one can assume $x$ is bounded away from zero. This is related to instrumentation measuring throughput, which is usually defined with an error in terms of percentage. I was surprised not able to find literature about this in statistics; maybe I am overlooking something.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood where $\mu_X$ came in there.

Comment: What is the difference between the true/unknown $\delta$ and $x$? It appears they should be equal (I am not referring to the readings).

Comment: maybe I misunderstand, but what about modelling it as a lognormal distribution?  $x_i=x e^{\epsilon_X}$.  This is pretty standard representation ( eg for share prices) and there should be suitable statistical tests documented

Comment: Thanks @AlecosPapadopoulos: yes, $\delta = x$ in the model; but we don't have access to the true $\delta$ or $x$.

Comment: @seanv507: Seems interesting, although slightly different representation.

Comment: Are the true $x$ and $\delta$ treated as deterministic, or as random variables? It doesn't matter whether they remain unknown, this is a critical aspect of the whole framework.

Comment: @caya - that's the point. $x(1+ \epsilon_X)\approx x e^x$ for small  $\epsilon_X$ but using exponentials is much more mathematically tractable. which is precisely why people work with exponentials in mathematical finance rather than percentage change ( even though the ordinary language of finance is % change just as you have). In particular $\log x_i$ is not heteroscedastic (using the exponential model)

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: yes, $x$ and $\delta$ vary themselves on each "reading", so they should be treated as random variables. And $\sigma_D$ is lot bigger than $\sigma_X$, which makes finding out $\mu_X$ harder imho.

Comment: @seanv507: yes, understood that; with the additional benefit that $e^{\epsilon_X}$ is always a positive factor, which is not captured in my model and probably wrong! However, I am still at odds to _justify_ the exponential model beyond that... Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: The fact that they vary does not necessarily make them random variables. If throughput is programmed in advance in some sense, its variability is deterministic, not random. So?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, I know and they are random. Imagine people taking water out from a reservoir, not everybody will take the same amount of water out of it. Arguably, there is some sort of distribution in the water taken :) but probably not much relevant, I guess.

Comment: @seanv507: I took your suggestion and developed an approach based on $Ln(x_i)-Ln(\delta_i)$ which behaves quite well too, although not yet formally approached as the answer just posted by Papadopoulus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will change notation to simplify.  Using information provided by the OP in the comments,

We have a latent, unobservable random variable $Y$. We measure this random variable through two different methods, each with measurement error. These methods are represented as

$$X_i = Y_i(1+u_i), \qquad u_i \sim N(\mu_{u}, \sigma^2_{u}),\;\; i=1,...,n$$

with $Y_i$ independent of $u_i$

and

$$Z_i = Y_i+w_i, \qquad w_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_{w}),\;\; i=1,...,n$$

with $w_i$ independent of $Y_i$

Our interest lies in whether $\mu_{u} =0$ or not.

Now, it is a crucial assumption that $Y$ is a random variable (and not deterministic), and also that it is an ergodic-stationary variable. If $Y$ was deterministic, then the random variable $X$ would not have a constant variance for each $i$. If $Y$ was a random variable but not ergodic/stationary, then again $X$ would not have a constant variance. $u$ is ergodic/stationary by construction, and the same holds for $Z$.

Since both $Y$ and $u$ are ergodic/stationary, then their product is also ergodic/stationary. So

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = Var(Y+Yu) $$
and constant $\forall i$, and consistently estimated by the sample variance.
Then:

Combine the two functional equations of the measurements to obtain (solving for $Y_i$ and equating)

$$X_i = (Z_i -w_i)+Y_iu_i \Rightarrow E(X_i) = E(Z_i) - E(w_i) + E(Y_iu_i)$$

$$\Rightarrow E(X_i) = E(Z_i) + E(Y_i)E(u_i)$$

where we have used the assumption of independence between $Y_i$ and $u_i$ to separate the expected value.

Under a null assumption

$$H_o: E(u_i) = \mu_{u}=0 \Rightarrow E(X_i) = E(Z_i)$$

and we can apply a [Welch's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) for the equality of means, using sample means and sample variances of $X$ and $Z$.

Again, it is critical that we can assume that the $X$ series has a constant variance.

**ADDENDUM**

We have that $E(Z) = E(Y)$. Applying a Method-of Moments approach

We have

$$E(X) = E(Z) + E(Y)E(u)= E(Z)\cdot [1+E(u)] \Rightarrow E(u)=\mu_u = \frac {E(X)}{E(Z)} -1$$

So

$$\hat \mu_u = \frac {(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nz_i} -1$$

The (additional) critical assumption for the Welch's test and for this estimator, is that $Y_i$ is independent of $u_i$, and so we can separate the expected value $E(Yu) = E(Y)E(u)$.

Comment: So, what I said "it seems I have heteroscedasticity in the model" is basically wrong. Is this what you are saying by $Var(X_i)$ = $Var(Y~+~Yu)$? On the other hand, your approach (kind of) reflects what I was thinking of adding up multiple instances of the $Z_i$; but then suggests an appropriate statistical tests for that: what I was looking for!

Comment: It is not "wrong". It would reflect different assumptions (e.g. $Y_i$ being deterministic and non-constant). If _my_ assumptions are an acceptable description of the real-world phenomenon behind these symbols (the critical assumption about $Y_i$ being an ergodic/stationary process), then, indeed, no-heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Thanks. I bet one can modify your answer slightly, and use it to calculate $\mu_u$; not just a simple test with p-value, etc. right?

Comment: Certainly, under the whole set of assumptions. Added it to complete.